# Showing a member channel entries

Tags: channel-entries, entries, solspace-user, users

I am trying to display a member channel entries using the tag {member_id} in the author_id parameter.
Unfortunately the parse order is messing it up, I have tried using the parse="inward" parameter, it made no difference, i have also tried using Stash.

It works fine if i use a {segment} in the URL, but i don't want to do this. I am using an embed and placing the {member_id} as an embed variable to pass to the channel call.

Is there a way to show an users entries without having their member ID in the URL?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try by passing the parameter `author_id="CURRENT_USER"`